# Elasticsearch Node IP address and other details using java rest high level client

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

How can we get node details for elasticseacrh using java high level rest client.
We can get node details in KIbana using **GET /_cat/nodes** .
I want to how to get same details using high level rest client , i need IP address of nodes and wether its master node or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like JHLRC doesn't have a API to get `_cat/nodes` API, but it can be easily obtained using the low-level client which is available within JHLRC as shown in below code

```
private void getNodesAPI(RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient) throws IOException {
        RestClient lowLevelClient = restHighLevelClient.getLowLevelClient();
        Request request = new Request(
                "GET",
                "/_cat/nodes?v");
        Response response = lowLevelClient.performRequest(request);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            System.out.println("resp: \n"+ EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
        }
    }
```

**Ran above code locally and it works and below is the O/P on console**

```
ip        heap.percent ram.percent cpu load_1m load_5m load_15m node.role master name
127.0.0.1           48          99  21    2.59    1.93     1.92 *    opster
```